# Gmail: create warning when link is different from displayed link

Tags: hyperlink, gmail

I use Gmail from Edge.
I often encounter some broadcasted mails such as conference invitations.
Sometimes I want to look at the details.

The problem is that the links in the letter look legit, like the following:
https://www.spectrumconferences.com/2024/isaset
but the actual link which would be opened is like
https://0tnys.mjt.lu/lnk/AVUAAB6C9AkjygvhgkjhjAAAAAAjt3XcAAAasdadAAB86TwBkr7E...
which I apparently don't want to click.

I currently have to hover over the link each time to check whether it would take me to the site it displays. Is there any extension/option/plugin for Gmail to highlight links where the displayed link differs from the actual link?